# stdole2.tlb Windows 10 vs stdole2.tlb on earlier versions of Windows

Tags: windows, ms-access

I have an Access 2016 application to install on various Windows versions that displays Access graphs.  The app developed on Win8.1 using Access 2010 works on 8.1 and earlier versions but the Access 2016 graphs do not work on Win8.1 because of an OLE server error.

Upgraded to MS Access 2016 on Win8.1 from MS Access 2010 because the MS Access 2010 runtime does not work on Windows 10 (acknowledged by Microsoft).

The MS Access error is: "An error occurred while sending data to the OLE server (the application used to create the object)".

I thought the problem was the installation of MS Access 2016 so I re-installed it but now see that the stdole2.tlb file dated April 2018 on Windows 10 is different from the stdole2.tlb file dated August 2013 on Windows 8.1 and earlier versions.

I'm not sure what the solution should be but if I could install the latest version of stdole2.tlb on all computers this might solve the problem but this would have to be done with the program installer.  I need the application to display graphs on all versions of Windows after version 7.

Comment: I installed the access 2010 runtime on a gazillion number of windows 10 machines. No issues, or even knowledge base articles from Microsoft exist or suggest that access 2010, or 2010 runtime has ANY issues at all when deployed onto windows 10 boxes.

Comment: Hi Albert, 

I agree but the problem is not Access 2010 as the app runs fine on Access 2010.  The problem is with Access 2016 and the OLE server which I presume is stdole2.tlb which is different on Win10 than on other versions of Windows.  If a graph is created in Access 2016 on Win8.1 or earlier (in my case) the graph gives the above error message when opened. 

Thanks

Comment: Albert,
Here is the System Requirements for Access Runtime 2010 from Microsoft: Supported Operating System
Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows Server 2003 R2 (32-Bit x86), Windows Server 2003 R2 x64 editions, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2008 Service Pack 2, Windows Vista Service Pack 1, Windows XP Service Pack 3

Only the 32-bit Access 2010 Runtime is supported on Windows XP Service Pack 3.

Maybe this is not up-to-date but Access 2016 produces errors on Windows 8.1 such as the ribbon menu is automatically loaded in Access 2016 and the graphs that depend on stdole2.tlb don't work.

Comment: So then  Access 2010 is fine! The issue seems to be installing Access/office 2016 on windows 8.1. That is a very different issue. If office 2016 not supported on windows 8.1, then you better continue to develop to the lowest common system. You can easily continue to develop with access 2010, and deploy using 2010 runtime, or even deploy the 2010 application with the 2016 runtime. However, if access/office 2016 don't work or install correctly on windows 8.1, then there not a lot you can do. Our industry NEVER supports going backwards, and you can't install 2010 on DOS 5.0 OR win 3.1 either.

Comment: Thanks Albert,
That's what I decided to do.  I added a trap for the stdole2 version date explaining the user might have an outdated file.  There is not much else that can be done since it's an OS issue (an Access issue too but there is no solution in Access).  It's not just Windows 8.1 because I have a client running Windows 10 and my access 2010 runtime which causes the same problem and is the reason for this Question.